# SqlKata SUM and Update

Tags: sqlkata

Is it possible to sum up a column directly with update?

RAW SQL:

```
UPDATE table SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id=1
```

SqlKata code:

```
q.From("table") _
.Where("id", 1) _
.AsUpdate(new With {
  .likes = 1 
 })
```

Comment: I just wanted to suggest to post in on github but you have already done this: https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/issues/290

Comment: Currently there is no option like this

Comment: asyncerror, Did you got an answer for this, I need this exact scenario.

Comment: @MadhankumarD there is no option for that. You need to retrieve the value from database, then sum in ASP.NET and update the database with the new value.